# Android 4.1 virtual keyboard freeze

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have the following strange issue that only occurs on Android 4.1: When the virtual keyboard is opened and the user presses the BACK button, my app just freezes and doesn't react any longer. After a while a system dialog box pops up informing me that the app has died and will be closed. I can hardly imagine that this is a bug in Android because hiding the keyboard by pressing the BACK button is elementary functionality that should just work. Still, my code is so small that I can almost completely rule out an error in my code.

Here is my code for you to review:

```
static int quit = 0;

static void engine_handle_cmd(struct android_app *app, int32_t cmd)
{       
        switch(cmd) {
        case APP_CMD_TERM_WINDOW:
                quit = 1;
                break;
        }
}

static int32_t engine_handle_input(struct android_app *app, AInputEvent *event)
{       
        switch(AInputEvent_getType(event)) {
        case AINPUT_EVENT_TYPE_MOTION: {
                int action = AMotionEvent_getAction(event);
                if((action & AMOTION_EVENT_ACTION_MASK) == AMOTION_EVENT_ACTION_DOWN) showkeyboard(app);                
                break;
                }                               
        }

        return 0;
}

void android_main(struct android_app* state)
{       
        int events, fd;
        struct android_poll_source *source;

        app_dummy();

        state->onAppCmd = engine_handle_cmd;
        state->onInputEvent = engine_handle_input;

        while(!quit) {
                if(ALooper_pollOnce(-1, &fd, &events, (void **) &source) >= 0) {
                        if(source) source->process(state, source);                                      
                }
        }       

        exit(0);
}
```

The showkeyboard() function is implemented in JNI like this:

```
static void showkeyboard(struct android_app* state)
{
        // Attaches the current thread to the JVM.
        jint lResult;
        jint lFlags = 0;
        JavaVM *lJavaVM = state->activity->vm;
        JNIEnv *lJNIEnv = state->activity->env;
        JavaVMAttachArgs lJavaVMAttachArgs;
        jobject lNativeActivity, INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE;
        jclass ClassNativeActivity, ClassContext;
        jfieldID FieldINPUT_METHOD_SERVICE;
        JNIEnv *env;
        int attached = 0;

        // must check if we're already attached!
        switch((*lJavaVM)->GetEnv(lJavaVM, (void**) &env, JNI_VERSION_1_6)) {
        case JNI_OK:
                break;
        case JNI_EDETACHED:
                lJavaVMAttachArgs.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6;
                lJavaVMAttachArgs.name = "NativeThread";
                lJavaVMAttachArgs.group = NULL;

                lResult = (*lJavaVM)->AttachCurrentThread(lJavaVM, &lJNIEnv, &lJavaVMAttachArgs);
                if(lResult == JNI_ERR) return;          

                attached = 1;
                break;

        case JNI_EVERSION:
                return;  // Invalid Java version
        }

        // Retrieves NativeActivity.
        lNativeActivity = state->activity->clazz;
        ClassNativeActivity = (*lJNIEnv)->GetObjectClass(lJNIEnv, lNativeActivity);

        // Retrieves Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE.
        ClassContext = (*lJNIEnv)->FindClass(lJNIEnv, "android/content/Context");

        FieldINPUT_METHOD_SERVICE = (*lJNIEnv)->GetStaticFieldID(lJNIEnv, ClassContext, "INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE", "Ljava/lang/String;");
        INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE = (*lJNIEnv)->GetStaticObjectField(lJNIEnv, ClassContext, FieldINPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
{
        // Runs getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE).
        jclass ClassInputMethodManager = (*lJNIEnv)->FindClass(lJNIEnv, "android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager");
        jmethodID MethodGetSystemService = (*lJNIEnv)->GetMethodID(lJNIEnv, ClassNativeActivity, "getSystemService", "(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;");
        jobject lInputMethodManager = (*lJNIEnv)->CallObjectMethod(lJNIEnv, lNativeActivity, MethodGetSystemService, INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

        // Runs getWindow().getDecorView().
        jmethodID MethodGetWindow = (*lJNIEnv)->GetMethodID(lJNIEnv, ClassNativeActivity, "getWindow", "()Landroid/view/Window;");
        jobject lWindow = (*lJNIEnv)->CallObjectMethod(lJNIEnv, lNativeActivity, MethodGetWindow);
        jclass ClassWindow = (*lJNIEnv)->FindClass(lJNIEnv, "android/view/Window");
        jmethodID MethodGetDecorView = (*lJNIEnv)->GetMethodID(lJNIEnv, ClassWindow, "getDecorView", "()Landroid/view/View;");
        jobject lDecorView = (*lJNIEnv)->CallObjectMethod(lJNIEnv, lWindow, MethodGetDecorView);

        // Runs lInputMethodManager.showSoftInput(...).
        jmethodID MethodShowSoftInput = (*lJNIEnv)->GetMethodID(lJNIEnv, ClassInputMethodManager, "showSoftInput", "(Landroid/view/View;I)Z");
        (*lJNIEnv)->CallBooleanMethod(lJNIEnv, lInputMethodManager, MethodShowSoftInput, lDecorView, lFlags);

        if(attached) {
                // Finished with the JVM.
                (*lJavaVM)->DetachCurrentThread(lJavaVM);
        }
}
}
```

To reproduce, you just have to compile the app, put it onto the emulator with an Android 4.1 image, then click somewhere and the virtual keyboard will be shown. Now try to close the keyboard using the BACK button. The app will freeze now.

Note that this error only occurs on Android 4.1. It works fine on 2.3, 3.0 and 4.0. Could this be a major bug in Android itself? I really have no other explanation because my code is really just a primitive main loop that doesn't do anything at all. But still, trying to close the virtual keyboard will crash the app.

Thanks a lot for help on this issue! I have been grappling with this for hours now :(

**UPDATE 1:**
The issue also appears on Android 4.2. A ticket has been opened on the Android issues site. Everybody who experiences the same problem should comment on the ticket so that the Android developers become aware of it. Here is the link:
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=43817&thanks=43817&ts=1359632204

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for asking this, it helped me.

I was seeing the freezes too. It seems to be coming from AInputQueue_preDispatchEvent in process_input in android_native_app_glue.c. To work around it, I changed:

```
LOGI("New input event: type=%d\n", AInputEvent_getType(event));
if (AInputQueue_preDispathEvent(app->inputQueue, event)) {
    return;
}
int32_t handled = 0;
```

to:

```
int32_t type = AInputEvent_getType(event);
LOGI("New input event: type=%d\n", type);
if (!g_iShowingSoftKeyboard || (type != AINPUT_EVENT_TYPE_KEY)
    || (AKeyEvent_getKeyCode(event) != AKEYCODE_BACK))
{
    if (AInputQueue_preDispathEvent(app->inputQueue, event)) {
        return;
    }
}
int32_t handled = 0;
```

of course g_iShowingSoftKeyboard is the global that I am using that is true if the soft keyboard is showing.

Edit: and I close the soft keyboard where I handle the back press in my input handler.